# Describing a Smile

Tags: book, narrative

Im trying to show the fact that in a picture my character is smiling, but I don't want to say

"we were smiling"

this is the sentence im trying to fix: **"We were both smiling foolishly, he looked so handsome in his tuxedo and honestly, I looked pretty good in my dress."**

I can't think of any other way of saying it, but I know it can be worded differently. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's wrong with "smiling"? It seems like to the most honest, direct way of communicating what is happening.

Comment: You’ve used the [[tag:brainstorming]] tag, but its description is *“For questions about brainstorming **techniques**. Do not use this tag to request help in brainstorming ideas for your work; those questions are **off-topic**.”* (emph added)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to describe the apparent feelings of the people in the photo.

> "He looked so handsome in his tuxedo, I looked pretty good in my dress, and we both looked like we'd just heard something hilarious. We hadn't, it was just anticipation of the moment, I remember it felt like waking up on Christmas morning when I was a kid."

Answer (score 2):

An appearance described in isolation may be weak, to reinforce it describe as the result of an interaction.

A smile could be something that your face does when it is affected by emotions, or it could be the result of behaviour in a social setting.

Describe the interaction between the characters the smile will just pop in there.

"He looked so handsome in his tuxedo. Our eyes met, a foolish look on his face. He glanced at my dress, my face warming with the thought of his smile touching mine."

You get the idea!